# Preventing the Construction of a "Raw Type" Reference

Tags: java, generics

The Jackson Core library contains the `TypeReference` abstract class.

This class implements `Comparable`. The [JavaDoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) explains why:

It uses a...

> ...bogus implementation of Comparable (any such generic interface would do, as long as it forces a method with generic type to be implemented), to ensure that a Type argument is indeed given.

and:

> `compareTo()`: The only reason we define this method (and require implementation of Comparable) is to prevent constructing a reference without type information.

An example of using `TypeReference` *with* type information (`Map<String, Object>`):

```java
String json = "{ \"some_key\": 123 }";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>(){};
Map<String, Integer> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
```

(The class is abstract, but it contains an implementation of `compareTo()` - so I don't need to provide one.)

The above technique does not stop me from constructing a reference *without* type information. The following compiles successfully (although the end result is not useful):

```java
// bad idea - just for illustration:
TypeReference typeReference2 = new TypeReference() {};
```

**What am I missing about the use of `Comparable` here? It does not prevent code compilation. I don't see how it could.**

Compiler warnings are a different matter - I'm wondering specifically about the "prevention" claim.

---

**Background Notes**:

If I try to use my raw type `typeReference2`, it will throw a *runtime* exception, because of the following [check in the constructor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/7f6c5060ca5ee4c754e528837d918d04763e517c/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java#L34):

```java
Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
}
```

The Javadoc for the class refers to [an article](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) which discusses the above runtime technique. It seems that a comment in that article prompted the inclusion of `Comparable` in Jackson's `TypeReference` class:

> Rather than check for a type parameter in the constructor, you can make it a syntax error to leave out:
>
> ```
> public abstract TypeReference<R> implements Comparable<TypeReference<R>> {
>     // ...
>     public int compareTo(TypeReference<R> o) {
>         // Need a real implementation.
>         // Only saying "return 0" for illustration.
>         return 0;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now this is legal:
>
> `new TypeReference<Object>() { };`
>
> But this is a syntax error for not implementing Comparable:
>
> `new TypeReference() { };`

I do not see this as a syntax error for `TypeReference`. It compiles OK, and [we've been given an implementation in the class already](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/7f6c5060ca5ee4c754e528837d918d04763e517c/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java#L55).

Comment: The article you cite is from 2006.  It's likely I think that changes in Java since then have rendered the article's syntax inoperative.  It's possible that `Comparable` *is* being implemented by the newer type inference systems, for example.  I'm not a expert though so I can't say exactly why this code compiles now.  It's just obvious that it does.

Comment: I notice that @rzwitserloot has filed a bug report about this. The [bug report](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/697). The related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269472/why-com-fasterxml-jackson-core-type-typereference-implements-comparable-interfac).