# why com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference implements Comparable interface?

Tags: java, jackson, comparable

Why do **com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference** implements **Comparable interface**?

I don't understand the intention of implementing it.

```
public abstract class TypeReference<T> implements Comparable<TypeReference<T>> {
    protected final Type _type;
    
    protected TypeReference() {
        Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
        }
        /* 22-Dec-2008, tatu: Not sure if this case is safe -- I suspect
         *   it is possible to make it fail?
         *   But let's deal with specific
         *   case when we know an actual use case, and thereby suitable
         *   workarounds for valid case(s) and/or error to throw
         *   on invalid one(s).
         */
        _type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Type getType() { return _type; }
    
    /**
     * The only reason we define this method (and require implementation
     * of <code>Comparable</code>) is to prevent constructing a
     * reference without type information.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TypeReference<T> o) { return 0; }
    // just need an implementation, not a good one... hence ^^^
}
```

Here's the source code description, but I still can't understand it.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: It does nothing and is a bug.

Did you *read* the source code? Because it explains it quite well.

Specifically, it links to [Neal Gafter's post on Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) and explicitly explains that the Comparable stuff is there 'inspired by a comment'. So, open that link, scroll down to the comments, and sure enough:

> Brian Oxley said...
> Rather than check for a type parameter in the constructor, you can make it a syntax error to leave out:
>
> ```
> public abstract TypeReference<R> implements Comparable<TypeReference<R>> {
>   // ...
>   
>   public int compareTo(TypeReference<R> o) {
>     // Need a real implementation.
>     // Only saying "return 0" for illustration.
>     return 0;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Now this is legal:
>
> `new TypeReference<Object>() { };`
>
> But this is a syntax error for not implementing `Comparable`:
>
> `new TypeReference() { }`;
>
> *February 20, 2007 6:12 AM*

*However*, **that is incorrect**.

It actually does nothing. Here, let's try it:

```
> cat Test.java
import java.lang.reflect.*;
abstract class TypeReference<T> implements Comparable<TypeReference<T>> {
  protected final Type _type;
  protected TypeReference() {
    Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
    }
    _type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(TypeReference<T> o) { return 0; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypeReference raw = new TypeReference() {};
  }
}

> javac Test.java
```

See? Compiles fine. If you run it, you get that 'sanity check' exception. The comparator stuff does nothing.

---

EDIT:

I filed a bug over at jackson about it [Issue #697](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/697).

To try to explain what the thought behind all this was (even though it does not work):

A raw type is infectious, and all aspects related to it are also raw. Raw types behaviour in unique ways, but usually those ways are very similar to having `Object` for *all* type variables, even if there is a lower bound.

Thus, `new TypeReference() {}`, being raw, means the `Comparable` it implements is also raw, which acts as if it's like Object, which means that the impl must have the method `public int compareTo(Object o)`.

The provided implementation of `TypeReference` *does not have* `int compareTo(Object)`, it only has `compareTo(TypeReference)`, therefore, `new TypeReference() {}` wouldn't compile.

A nice story. But that's not how javac works, unfortunately. You can see the logic and it makes some sense, but unfortunately that `compareTo`, because it matches the lower bound, gets a synthetic additional method. You can check this: If you `javap` TypeReference:

```
> javap TypeReference
javap TypeReference
Compiled from "Test.java"
abstract class TypeReference<T> implements java.lang.Comparable<TypeReference<T>> {
  protected final java.lang.reflect.Type _type;
  protected TypeReference();
  public int compareTo(TypeReference<T>);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
```

Note how there are two `compareTo` methods in the class file even though we wrote only one in the source. Thus, any classes that `extends TypeReference` will always have, baked in, an impl for `compareTo(Object)` no matter what you try to hack with the generics part of it.

Comment: You answered [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944812/preventing-the-construction-of-a-raw-type-reference), also. +1